# Does Azure Databricks use Query Acceleration in Azure Data Lake Storage?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Does Azure Databricks use the query acceleration functions in Azure Data Lake Storage gen2?  In [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-query-acceleration#applications-that-can-benefit-from-query-acceleration) we can see that spark can benefit from this functionality.

I'm wondering if, in the case where I only use the delta format, I'm profiting from this functionality and whether to include it in the pricing in Azure Calculator under the Storage Account section?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-query-acceleration)

```
Query acceleration supports CSV and JSON formatted data as input to each request.
```

So it doesn't work with Parquet or Delta - because it is fundamentally a row based accelerator, and Parquet is a columnar format.